# Slice and splice in not working on array values

Tags: javascript

```
exp: finalValueArr["4", "4", "+", "2", "2"];

        finalValueArr = finalValue.split("");
        findOpr = finalvaluearr.indexOf("+");

        if(findOpr != null){
        oprPos = parseInt(findOpr);

        FirstOperand = finalvaluearr.splice(0, oprPos);
        SecondOperand = finalvaluearr.splice(1, -1);
```

Here i am trying to divide array value in two variable first slice is working but last is not working i have use slice also but i get NAN in last value of second variable any solution for this issue please help

Comment: What does `exp: finalValueArr["4", "4", "+", "2", "2"];` mean?

Comment: You can try [Array.slice(begin, end)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)

Comment: after split variable value

Comment: This question would be easier to answer if you could include any error messages you get and what you expect the value of `SecondOperand` to be

Comment: Code shown is not valid and has typos. `finalvaluearr !== finalValueArr`. Please provide proper code, errors thrown and expected results

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest to use [`Array#slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) instead of [`Array#splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice), because slice does not change the array (if it is not necessary).

[`Array#indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) returns the index if found and `-1` if not found.

```js
var finalValue = '44+22',
    finalValueArr = finalValue.split(''),
    oprPos = finalValueArr.indexOf('+'),        // result is index, if found, or -1
    operand1,
    operand2;

if (~oprPos) { // checks if oprPos !== -1
    operand1 = finalValueArr.slice(0, oprPos);  // slice instead of splice, it does
    operand2 = finalValueArr.slice(oprPos + 1); // not mutilate the original array
}

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(finalValueArr, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(operand1, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(operand2, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 1):

In the line `finalvaluearr.splice(1, -1)`, you are passing `-1` as the second parameter. This is your problem, as this number should be either 0 or a positive integer - read more in the [spec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

If you only want to get the rest of the elements in an array from a specified position:

```
finalvaluearr.splice(1)
```

Comment: But i need last value of array from 1 pos to last pos

Comment: Then just omit the second argument.

Comment: it is store only one value

Comment: ok, can you post exactly what the value of `SecondOperand` should be?

Comment: I am working on a calculator program i need to divide the array value in two variable . how can i do it